# How do you cast an object to an interface it implements but doesn't extend?

Tags: c#, class, interface, scripting, casting

I have a class `Script`, which has several properties but no methods. Classes are then created extending `Script`. Ideally a script might have the method `Update()` but wouldn't extend the interface `IUpdateable` (which has a method 'Update' specified). When this script is added to an object the object would then realize that, while the object doesn't extend `IUpdateable`, it is still an implementation of it. It would then add the script to a list of scripts with Update methods, so it could be updated.

My question centres around two things, how can I tell if a class implements an interface (without extending it), and, armed with that knowledge, how do I cast it to an object whose `Update()` method can be called.

Are there other options that I should consider instead?

Thanks

Comment: I think you may get some confused answers based on your use of terminology here. Only an interface extends another interface - and "implementing" an interface really does mean having it in the declaration, e.g. `class Foo : IBar`. I suspect you mean "How can I tell if a class supports all the members required by an interface, without actually implementing it?" Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Reflection for this.

To check if a class implements an interface, try the below -

```
typeof(IMyInterface).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(MyType))

typeof(MyType).GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IMyInterface))
```